# Find unused properties in destructured parameter object in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, destructuring

We would like to detect (with ESlint or typescript for exemple) unused properties in the type of destructured params in Typescript, such as "c" in the following example

```
const myIncompletelyRefactoredFunction = ({a, b}: {a: number, b: number, c: number}) => a + b
```

No-unused-var allows us to dectect cases such as:

```
//ts-error
const myIncompletelyRefactoredFunction = ({a, b, c}: {a: number, b: number, c: number}) => a + b
```

But the refactoring is not complete in this case, that's we would like to detect.

Our use case here is our React components with dozens of props, where the type still require props although they are not used anymore

Thank you

Comment: I can see your requirement. Though I think it might be an antipattern: Types should be reusable and not throw if a property isn't used.
Maybe this would be a case for a custom rule to implement?

Comment: hi ! thanks for the tip. Maybe it can be a rule such as "no-unused-local-type-property" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody has made a rule proposal for your use-case here:
https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1529

Enjoy!